# Uniform convergence of expectation?

Tags: probability, convergence, probability-inequalities

Let $U_i$, $i = 1 ,2\dots, $ be i.i.d. standard normal random variables. For every $n$,  let $f_n:\Theta  \times \mathbb R^{n} \to [0, 1]$, where $\Theta$ is some compact subset of $\mathbb R$ [may even be taken to be some closed ball]. Define $\mu_n(\theta) = \mathbb E f_n(\theta, U_1, \dots, U_n)$.

**Q: Is it true in general that**

$$
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} \frac{\mathbb E \left[ f_n(\theta, U_1, \dots, U_n)n^{-2}\sum_{i = 1}^n\vert U_i\vert\right]}{\mu_n(\theta)} \to 0 ?
$$

---

If it is not true in general, I'm also interested in conditions that make it true.

Comment: Is there a typo here? As written, the denominator $\mu_n(\theta)$ will cancel with the first term in the numerator, which would trivially imply the result from the SLLN.

Comment: @AlexR. Added brackets to avoid confusion.

Comment: If $\mu_n(\theta)>\epsilon>0$ is true, then the result follows immediately after bounding $f_n$ in the numerator by 1.

Comment: Thanks @AlexR. Unfortunately, in my application, I cannot lower bound the expectation. In fact, I suspect $\mu_n(\theta) \to 0$ for every $\theta$, but I'm not sure of this.

Comment: Can you guarantee $\mu_n(\theta)=o(1/n)$ for all $n$ large enough?

Comment: @AlexR. No not really, I don't know much about $\mu_n$.